# Controlling more than one data line of the parallel port in Python

Tags: python, email, parallel-processing, led

As of yesterday I started a little project, but I'm already hung up and after searching and searching I've not been able to find a solution.

I've seen people use Arudino's for all kinds of things, but I don't have the money for one so I got to thinking maybe I could use my computers parallel port in a similar way.

I found pyParallel which has allowed me hook some simple things up the the port and use them. My end goal is to have a small program check my email and light up a few LEDS (one for each email account) when I have mail, as well as turn on and off my desklamp.

I know how to do all the electronics side of this, but the programming is confusing me. I've never done anything with Python up until this point (I do have knowledge of other languages though) and I've never controlled something physical like this before either.

A basic example I was able to get working is this...

```
import parallel, imaplib, re
p = parallel.Parallel()

connXp = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
connXp.login("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
unreadXp = re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", connXp.status("INBOX", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1)

if (unreadXp > "0"):
    p.setData(1 << 0)

else:
    p.setData(0 << 0)
```

Adding a second account to the code is easy enough and I've gotten it to check several of my Email addresses just fine, but I can't for the life of me make it light up more then one LED at a time.

What I want to do is check for email on Email#1 (we'll call it that) and if there's unread messages turn the LED connected to datapin 0 on, if there are none turn it/leave it off, at which point I want to then check Email#2 and do the same on datapin 1 while leaving the first LEDs state alone.

Once I get this working I'll likely just set it up as a cron job and run it every minute to check or so.

I greatly appreciate any help you can give as I really have no clue where to go from here.

(If it matters I'm running this on the newest version of Ubuntu with Python 2.7.5)

Comment: this should help http://www.bristolwatch.com/pport/pportbits.htm